# SSH Login With Security Question?

Tags: ssh

I Don't Know If This Is Possible. 
But Can i install anything or is possible to create any script which will be executet after i will login on my Ubuntu Server As Root?! 
An script with Ex, 3 security questions

Ex.

Q : **What is your birthday?!**

A : `10.10.10 // if not die ban4Life`

Is This possible?!
Thanks, And sorry for my *"ignorance"*

Comment: You can do that using `PAM` module, if you will write or find such.

Comment: i don't know to much for PAM, But i'll search on google about this. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A thought upfront: Why don't you stick to traditional password-based authentication or better yet [public-key authentication](//help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) like everybody else? Your solution is basically a second yet easier to guess password stored in plain text. Custom authentication schemes rarely increase and often even decrease security.*

---

If you don't like PAM you can configure SSH to use a particular log-in script for `root`. It may look something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

while read -rp 'What is your birthday?!' REPLY
do
    case "$REPLY" in
        '')
            # empty input; ask again
            ;;

        '10.10.10')
            # Run original command if available or simply the user's log-in shell
            exec ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND-$SHELL -l};;

        *)
            break;;
    esac
done

echo "You're not welcome here. Go away!" >&2
exit 1
```

Save the script, e. g. as `/root/login-with-birthday.sh`, make it executable and make sure that ordinary users cannot read the file because it contains a secret (`chmod 0700`). Then tell `sshd` to use it as the log-in command by adding a rule to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match user root
    ForceCommand /root/login-with-birthday.sh
```

Comment: Wow Thank You very much! i'm using public-key for my servers, 
but with one server which is for team work i will hide it. and i'm thinking to make one diferent and easy security because this server is for personal work not for public!

Comment: Why don't you use public-key authentication for the private server too? I do that with non-public facing servers too. It's super easy once you get the hang of it which seems to be the case for you.